Errors when installing Ubuntu on my MacBook Pro (2013 model). Bootable drive not working?
I'm trying to install Ubuntu on a 15" 2013 MacBook Pro. I used balenaEtcher for creating a bootable USB flash drive. With the bootable flash drive created, I am getting errors when trying to boot from the flash drive:
DMAR-IR [Firmware Bug]: ioapic 2 has no mapping iommu, interrupt remapping will be disabled
usb 4-1: device not accepting adress 2, error - 62 
usb 4-1: device not accepting adress 3, error - 62
usb 4-1: device not accepting adress 4, error - 71
usb 4-1: device not accepting adress 5, error - 71 
usb4-port1: unable to enumerate USB device

I have tried multiple things and now I am stuck.
